# Legacy solution with Aurelia

Tags: asp.net, aurelia

I have an old ASP.NET solution that I have introduced Aurelia to. In some aspx pages I am starting Aurelia, and my main.ts looks like this:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .basicConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging();
  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot('/Controls/Warehouse/ProductPurchaseSuggestion/AureliaSource/app.js'));
}
```

In this manner, everytime we use Aurelia, we have to start it up like this.

I was just composing in my first template and had to write this:

```
<compose view-model="/Controls/Warehouse/ProductPurchaseSuggestion/AureliaSource/mergePopup" model.bind="{ demo: 'test' }"></compose>
```

To compose it in. I would have thought that setRoot would make it possible for me to write:

```
<compose view-model="mergePopup" model.bind="{ demo: 'test' }"></compose>
```

If I do it like in the last example here (how I want it to work), then I get the following error message in the console: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: No view model found in module "mergePopup".`

Is there any way of being able to do it in this manner?

Comment: is it working without the `<compose>` tag? Are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: updated question with error message. What do you mean without the <compose> tag? If you mean the app.js is being loaded correctly, and the application works, then yes. Everything works fine if I don't compose in templates.

Comment: what mergePopup is? is it a view or a class? .html or .js?

Comment: both? :) It's Aurelia's convention...

Comment: in this case, you should use a customElement `<mergePopup></mergePopup>`. If you still want to use compose, try this `<compose view-model="mergePopup" view="mergePopup.html" model.bind="{ demo: 'test' }"></compose>`

Comment: What module loader are you using? Webpack, JSPM/SystemJS, or the Aurelia CLI?

Comment: @AshleyGrant jspm

Comment: @FabioLuz How would <mergePopup></mergePopup> work? Where would the argument for the activate method go? I have never seen anything like this been done. Do you have a jsfiddle or example?

Comment: @Bjørn custom-elements don't the `activate()` hook. But you could use bindable properties to pass values. See http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/9